# send data using android Bluetooth to Arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

Good day.

I want to send Accelerometer readings from the Android to Arduino using Bluetooth communication. I don't want to write the code to discover devices around and connect or connect to them through program interface . I can connect to the other device manually by the android setting.all I want to do is to send the string through output buffer or anything while i connect manually to the Arduino bluetooth but the tutorials out there shows how to connect and discover device.
I have been struggling to know how to send data (string or int) and i really don't care about discover and connect because i can do this manually from my android settings

thank you in advance

Comment: https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/

Comment: thank you ... seems like a related work that may help

Comment: you are welcome, Please put some effort from your side before ask any help from others.

Answer (score 0):

Sensors, Arduino devices and other hardware systems typically work on SERIAL PORT PROFILE (SIP). You may wanna double check this with the specific hardware you are dealing with. But I am quite sure it is SIP. If that is the case, you can literally copy and paste android chat sample code and change UUID to default UUID of Serial Port.

Just replace UUID of the sample with this: `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

The UUID is the chat example is defined in `BluetoothChatService.java`. You can change both secure and insecure UUIDs.

This is the sample: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat